"More stable" definitions of principal $G$-bundle
Let $G$ be a topological group. For any pointed topological space $X$, define $[X,G]$ to be the group whose underlying topological space is the space of pointed continuous maps from $X$ to $G$, with point-wise multiplication. Now, from the classical definition of principal group bundles for topological groups, it's clear that there can be no non-trivial principal group bundles over a point. However, it seems to me that such a definition is a bit "unstable". For example, consider the case where $G = U(1), X = S^2$. Then in terms of the classifying space, we can try to argue that
$\pi_0(B[S^2,U(1)]) \cong $ "$\pi_{-1}([S^2,U(1)])$" $ \cong \pi_1(U(1)) \cong \mathbb{Z}$
The part in quotes is obviously not well-defined, but is there some "more stable" definition of principal $G$-bundles where this calculation is correct, such that principal $[S^2,U(1)]$ bundles over a point are classified by $\mathbb{Z}$?

One could define your desired notion of a “principal [S^2, G]” bundle over X as a homotopy class of maps X -> [S^2, BG]. If X is a point then this is just the set pi_2(BG), which is indeed Z when G=U(1)

@skd Yeah, I see that, but I was hoping for some kind of interpretation of what it means.

It's a G-bundle over X x S^2, or equivalently a S^2-parametrized family of G-bundles on X. I'm not sure what sort of interpretation you're after.

@skd I guess I was looking for some argument for why this could be a "natural" definition of principal $G$-bundle. Or in other words: going from a group to its classifying space defines a functor from $\mathrm{TopGrp}$ to $\mathrm{hTop}$. Can one instead define a corresponding functor from $\mathrm{TopGrp}$ which, in particular, sends $[S^2,U(1)]$ into $[S^2,BU(1)]$?
